# Call a method by clicking a button in a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, action

I want to generate some HTML content and put this into a UIWebView. The HTML contains some buttons. Is it possible to define actions for these buttons? I want to call a method (e.g. firstButtonPressed) in my objective-c code when someone presses this button in the UIWebView.

Thanks you for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up on this, it is possible, and not to difficult to connect HTML/javascript events to objective-c methods.

Damien Berrigaud came up with a [good example](http://blog.meliondesign.com/2010/02/mapping-uiwebview-links-to.html) of how to do that by using `file://` links

```
// Map links starting with file://
//            ending with #action
// with the action of the controller if it exists.
//
// Open other links in Safari.
- (BOOL)webView: (UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  NSString *fragment, *scheme;

  if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    [webView stopLoading];
    fragment = [[request URL] fragment];
    scheme = [[request URL] scheme];

    if ([scheme isEqualToString: @"file"] && [self respondsToSelector: NSSelectorFromString(fragment)]) {
      [self performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(fragment)];
      return NO;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [request URL]];
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This link http://davinc.me/post/45670387932/call-ios-method-for-html-button-click help me to resolve the same problem.

For button

```
<a href="didTap://button1"><img src="button1.jpg" /></a>
```

Then become delegate of

> UIWebView

and then use

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"didTap://button1"]) {
        [self didTapButton1];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the phonegap project: [www.phonegap.com](http://www.phonegap.com)

It is designed to do this kind of thing and more. If anything you will be able to get an idea how to code this as the project is open source.