# Calling a native (ios)method from an embedded html page inside my IOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

I've been asked by a friend to make him a very simple app that launches and then loads a full screen UIWebview and displays some html pages that are inside the app. No problem there.

He also asked me to call a url scheme, which will launch another app already installed on the device. I've done the url scheme stuff to launch an app before, that's no problem.

What I don't understand is how to go about getting the html to call a method in my app.

To summarize:
So my app will have native code that will:

a) Show a UIWebview which will display html pages embedded into the app.
b) A method that does the URL scheme stuff to launch another app.

Question: How can I call my method via the html(html button) pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same question but you should connect your scheme request in this method.

[Stackoverflow- Call a method by clicking a button in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363375/call-a-method-by-clicking-a-button-in-a-uiwebview)

If you want to go more advanced you can use:

[WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge)